# AJAX Call in Wordpress is returning 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve some information from my database using ajax.

I created a plug in that inserts my javascript into my header of my page.  The code I am calling is as follows:

```
(function($){
$('#txtFname').on('input', function(){
var postData = $('#txtFname').val();
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
}
else{
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
document.getElementById("frmResult").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}    
};
var data= "action=myAjaxFunction="+postData;
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.my-site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", true);
xmlhttp.send(data);
});
})(jQuery);
```

In my functions.php file for my theme I am using I added the following(I just want to make sure its calling this function.  I already have working code to grab the data from the database):

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjaxFunction', 'myAjaxFunction' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myAjaxFunction', 'myAjaxFunction' );    
function myAjaxFunction(){ 
echo "This function is being called";
}
```

When I make a change to my txtFname input the output is 0;

I have looked through a lot of previous questions and not sure if I am missing something or just made a mistake in my code. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: you need to use `exit` in your php function

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
var data= "action=myAjaxFunction="+postData;
                                ^--
```

That'd produce

```
action=myAjaxFunction=foo
```

which PHP will parse into `$_POST['action'] = 'myAjaxFunction=foo'`

Comment: I changed that line of code to:  var data= "action=myAjaxFunction&txtFName="+postData;  with the same result.